# Why am I getting a save dialog box when I try to open phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache-2.2, suphp

I got my apache2 server running and using suphp. I get a php test file to work at `/var/www/html` and at `/home/usr/public_html`. When I step into server/phpmyadmin I get a file save dialog box. The link to `phpmyadmin.conf` is present in the `apache2/conf-enabled` directory. I tried changing `short_open_tag` to `On` in `php5/apache2/php.ini`, but that didn't help. I tried putting a php test script in the phpmyadmin directory and that too presented me with a save file dialog.

What to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP installation is not working. You marked the question with suPHP tag so I am guessing that you have installed mod_suphp (`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-suphp`)?

Also, make sure that mod_php is disabled (sudo a2dismod php5).

`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/suphp.conf` this file should also be present.

In your VHost for phpMyAdmin you should have something like this (replace nobody with whatever user you want to execute phpMyAdmin for you, this user should also have the ownership of the files, same for the group):

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The PHP test file works when called from the /var/www/html directory or the /home/user/public_html directory.

Comment: The libapache2-mod-suphp is installed and the latest version. the mod_php is disabled. the suphp.conf is enabled. I edited the apache.conf file in the phpmyadmin directory to include the above IfModule code but I had to comment out the suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody because the apache restart complained of bad config. "AH00526: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
Invalid command 'suPHP_UserGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed."  I am now getting code when trying to open phpmyadmin.